# AADSTS500011 - PowerBi C# .NET (resource x not found in tenant y)

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi

I am trying to integrate the power bi embedded with C#, I always have this same error that comes out, I put it to you just below, as well as the versions of the packages and the code (basic) which is supposed to do the work .

Thank you for all your answers

```
Microsoft.PowerBI.Api (v2.0.12)
Microsoft.PowerBI.JavaScript (v2.5.1)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (v3.13.9)
```

Microsoft PowerBI JavaScript (v2.5.1)
Microsoft IdentityModel Clients.ActiveDirectory (v3.13.9)

Note that the two head variables are temporary.
The error always come out at this line : `var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.resourceUrl, this.applicationId, credential);`

There is the error message : "exceptionMessage": "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/ was not found in the tenant named x. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

```
public async Task<EmbedConfigResource> EmbedReport([FromUri]string username, [FromUri]string roles)
    {
        roles = "None";
        username = this.pbiUsername;

        var result = new EmbedConfigResource { Username = username, Roles = roles };

        var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(this.pbiUsername, this.pbiPassword);
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.authorityUrl);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.resourceUrl, this.applicationId, credential);
        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(this.apiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(this.workspaceId);

            Report report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == this.reportId);

            var datasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdInGroupAsync(this.workspaceId, report.DatasetId);
            result.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired = datasets.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired;
            result.IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired = datasets.IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired;
            GenerateTokenRequest generateTokenRequestParameters;

            var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(this.pbiUsername, new List<string> { report.DatasetId });
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roles))
            {
                var rolesList = new List<string>();
                rolesList.AddRange(roles.Split(','));
                rls.Roles = rolesList;
            }

            generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view", identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { rls });

            var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(this.workspaceId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

            result.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
            result.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
            result.Id = report.Id;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must log into Azure portal, go to `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations`, select your app, click `View API permissions`, and then grant admin consent by clicking the button at the bottom:

[image]

If you don't have access to the portal, or the button is disabled, you must ask your admin to do it for you.